# What kind of screw is this and how do I open it?

Tags: electrical, tools, screws

[image]
[image]

These are screws all over my pc casing. I would like to open them but I dont know how, sorry for the bad quality picture, but I cant take a better one.

How do I open them?

EDIT:
As people have suggested I found the proper way to open some parts, they were hidden behind a big plastic cover, that was attached with many clickable sections. After open the cover there were the final screws I needed to open.

Comment: That appears to be a rivet made of aluminum.. You'd have to drill it out.

Comment: With drill it out you mean destroy the metal with a drill? Because I does not look like I could get grip to get it out, just kinda destroy the metal right?

Comment: An appropriate diameter drill, say twice the diameter of the rivet's dark center, can be used to drill through the rivet. Of course the rivet is then destroyed, but the case should be OK.  Now, the rivet might spin as you attempt to drill it. You might need to hold the rivet somehow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about PC repair.

Comment: For future reference with questions like this (whether on this forum or one that is more specific to computers as opposed to home improvement, though as you can see, people try to help if they can even when off-topic): **Include model #s**. If you included the model # (Dell or HP or Toshiba 'xyz123') then either someone would tell you exactly what to do from their own experience or be able to point you to an online instruction manual.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question I asked, although on a different network https://superuser.com/questions/980833/how-to-remove-circular-screws-for-5-drive-bay-are-they-rivets

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those are rivets and you can, in every case, open the case without removing the rivets.

If you need to remove the rivets, they can be drilled out.

Answer (score 11):

Red herring, those are not screws at all. They are rivets.  Rivets are permanent fasteners never meant to be undone, and are used in cases where welding would also be appropriate.  You wouldn't chisel off a weld, so don't chisel off a rivet.

Look elsewhere for the sanctioned/intended way to open up the case.